# On the Placement of a "See Also" Index Comment

Tags: cross-referencing, indexing, imakeidx, idxlayout

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
%\usepackage[font=normalsize]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\Large

This sentence is to be indexed.\index{FAMOUS QUOTES@\textbf{FAMOUS QUOTES}!01@ \textbf{\textit{\color{red}{Ich bin ein Berliner}}} \textit{See also}, \textbf{DOUGHNUT}}

Another to be indexed. 
\index{FAMOUS QUOTES@\textbf{FAMOUS QUOTES}!02@ \textbf{\textit{\color{red}{Denkansto{\ss}}}}}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the index:

[image]

I would like to place the "See also **DOUGHNUT**" comment a little to the right of the page number, and on the same line as "Ich bin ein Berliner". How may I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: your see also is just entered as free text so rather hard to control, why not use makeindex `|see` markup so the system at least knows this is a cross reference

Comment: @David Carlisle I tried that. When I put `|see{\textbf{DOUGHNUT}}` immediately to the left of the last closing brace, the page number disappears. Moreover, `|see` gives *see* and not *see also*.  And alas, if I place `|see{\textbf{DOUGHNUT}}` outside of the said closing brace, the comment does not appear at all. Hence, the makeshift way of the MWE.

Comment: `|see` just executes `\see` which is defined as `\newcommand*\see[2]{\emph{\seename} #1}` there is also `|seealso` defined as `\providecommand*\seealso[2]{\emph{\alsoname} #1}` and you could define `|seealsowithpage` that didn't discard `#2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a version of `|see` that does not discard the page number:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage% hmmm
\makeindex
%\usepackage[font=normalsize]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\seezz[2]{#2\quad\textit{see also} #1}

\begin{document}
\Large

This sentence is to be indexed.\index{FAMOUS QUOTES@\textbf{FAMOUS QUOTES}!01@ \textbf{\textit{\color{red}{Ich bin ein Berliner}}}|seezz{\textbf{DOUGHNUT}}}

Another to be indexed. 
\index{FAMOUS QUOTES@\textbf{FAMOUS QUOTES}!02@ \textbf{\textit{\color{red}{Denkansto{\ss}}}}}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you once again for your help.